# Releasing autorelease object does not crash my app why?

Tags: iphone, autorelease

why app does not crash when i release any autorelease object, or is it that my app will crash some time later when autorelease pool is drained?

Answer (score 1):

The crash would occur when the object is released more often that it is retained so in this case when the pool is drained.

Comment: or potentially even later when some other object that has a retained pointer to your object releases it...